# Slashy string null in groovy

Tags: groovy

Why this works in groovy:

```
def slashyNull = /${}/
println slashyNull
```

but this does not:

```
println /${}/
```

This ends up groovy giving compile time error on the next line "unexpected token }"

[image]

Ignore the first error: `Groovy: compiler mismatch Project level is...`

Comment: just in case: does this only happen in eclipse and what groovy version?

Answer (score 0):

For printing you have to put it in `()`: `println(/${}/)` (as it seems no longer unambigous).

Comment: escape `$` to get output as `null`? how? I dont think we can escape anything inside `/.../`

Comment: i have removed that part.  i thought, this was some attempt to get the string `${}`.

Comment: ohh good...but how `println /${}/` is ambiguous to `println`?

Comment: and that `println(/${}/)` prints `${}` not `null`. `def slashyNull = /${}/; println slashyNull` prints `null`. So definitely not one and same.

Comment: my guess for the reason would be the very last example (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString `assert (/ab/ == 'a' + 'b')  // brackets currently required if slashy string is on LHS`) and the explanation below. and it prints null for me (groovy 2.4.1)

Comment: nope my mistake `println (/${}/) ` also properly prints `null`

Comment: `brackets currently required if slashy string is on LHS` : they should say something more on this not just in the context of `assert()`

Comment: my guess there is more in the realm as the text below suggests: it's actually a problem with the parser and it's unintended, but right now it is what it is.

Comment: yep thats what they mean by *edge case in grammar*, may be they are somewhat unable to straighten this anomaly in grammar....just curious can we find code where this grammar is implemented...I mean I never dug inside language implementation, but now getin curious to see how the groovy grammar is implemented. Never tried such...but please do u know? Is it on github?

Comment: i have never fiddled with it myself.  but i guess a good start would be here https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g